# Where can I hear more music by Dragon Ball composer Shunsuke Kikuchi?

Tags: music, dragon-ball

I am a big fan of Shunsuke Kikuchi, the composer of the BGM (background music) for the Dragon Ball animes such as this one:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Apzgm_hpoZw

While I can only usually find his music for Dragon Ball online like YouTube, etc, I am wondering if some of his other works can be listened to online.

Comment: Maybe ask on [musicfans.se] instead?

Comment: @Unihedron of course, but asking here increases the chances of actually getting an answer? Anime and manga fans sometimes know Japanese culture while "music fans" forum is maybe a little less specific...

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/59039/japanese-culture?referrer=tP_lbamf0n1kK-dXh6v_KA2

Comment: @Unihedron what is this  link? I don't understand

Comment: Are you looking for a list of media he is [credited for](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/people.php?id=118) or a list of [individual pieces](http://www.last.fm/music/Shunsuke+Kikuchi/+charts?rangetype=week&subtype=tracks) he's worked on? You should be more specific on that you are looking for.

Comment: @ʞɹɐzǝɹ my question asks "where can his other works be heard online". Not sure how much more specific I could be... (Therefore, music pieces for which he is credited as a music composer). Thanks!

Comment: While it's a given that you did mention that, your title implies you're asking for a list of works, which brings into question which you are looking for more, or links to media. Both are broad questions, but the latter is a bit more so as rarely do the older japanese composers make or think to have their works (especially older ones) to be available online so much more effort is needed in digger them up. I only ask you this so be can better tailor an answer to what you specifically want more and not have to fumble around trying to cover all the bases.

Comment: @ʞɹɐzǝɹ Thank you very much for pointing this out, I instantly corrected the title of the question to better frame my intentions.

Answer (score 1):

The composer doesn't have a dedicated channel, as not many of his works are available for streaming or download legally online.

[A discography](http://www.discogs.com/artist/311877-Shunsuke-Kikuchi) and [filmography](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0452853/#soundtrack) of his work is available. As he has done work for not only anime, but live action series and films (as writer and/or composer), your best bet is to use a combination of two lists and look them up individually on sites such as Youtube.

Comment: Thank you very much. I hope that maybe, someone who is perfectly fluent in Japanese could also give their two cents about this, as there might be amazing amounts of information on such topics in Japanese websites that we cannot easily access.

Comment: @fabriced: He has numerous works: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%8F%8A%E6%B1%A0%E4%BF%8A%E8%BC%94 80% of his article on ja.Wikipedia is just for listing his works.

Comment: Thanks, @nhahtdh, I believe the US page on Wikipedia for him also has a good list of his works (and IMDb). 
But the link you are providing doesn't allow me to listen to any of his works, just to see a list of his works in Japanese.

Comment: @fabriced: The list is there. If you want to listen, you have to search for it. Do mind that the works are all copyrighted, so whether you find the soundtrack for free depends on your luck.